# Python client for Managing Kafka ACL

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python, confluent-kafka-python

Do we have any python client for managing Kafka ACL?
I know we have Java Admin client and same can be performed using Kafka scripts (kafka-acl.sh) but cannot find one for python client.
confluent python library doesn't support it. Came across [kafka-python](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaAdminClient.html) but as per documentation it doesn't support creating ACL for existing topics.

Comment: You could always use `os.subprocess` to call existing Kafka CLI commands. But I think it'd be a better idea to externalize the ACLs to a different solution like Apache Ranger or openpolicyagent

Answer (score 1):

###### Use kafka-python lib

###### configure acl, new add, example:

User `user1` has read access to `topic2` and `group2` groups (consumer)

User `user2` has write permission on `topic2` (producer)

```py
from kafka.admin import KafkaAdminClient, ACLPermissionType, ResourcePattern, ResourceType, ACL, ACLOperation, ACLFilter

brokers = 'localhost:9092'

admin = KafkaAdminClient(
    bootstrap_servers=brokers,
    security_protocol='SASL_PLAINTEXT',
    sasl_mechanism='SCRAM-SHA-512',
    sasl_plain_username='admin',      # your privileged user
    sasl_plain_password='admin12345'  # password
)


acl1 = ACL(
    principal="User:user1",
    host="*",
    operation=ACLOperation.READ,
    permission_type=ACLPermissionType.ALLOW,
    resource_pattern=ResourcePattern(ResourceType.TOPIC, 'topic2')
)
acl2 = ACL(
    principal="User:user1",
    host="*",
    operation=ACLOperation.READ,
    permission_type=ACLPermissionType.ALLOW,
    resource_pattern=ResourcePattern(ResourceType.GROUP, 'group2')
)
acl3 = ACL(
    principal="User:user2",
    host="*",
    operation=ACLOperation.WRITE,
    permission_type=ACLPermissionType.ALLOW,
    resource_pattern=ResourcePattern(ResourceType.TOPIC, 'topic2')
)


acls_result = admin.create_acls([acl1, acl2, acl3])
print(acls_result)
```

###### delete acls

```py
from kafka.admin import KafkaAdminClient, ACLPermissionType, ResourcePattern, ResourceType, ACL, ACLOperation, ACLFilter

brokers = 'localhost:9092'

admin = KafkaAdminClient(
    bootstrap_servers=brokers,
    security_protocol='SASL_PLAINTEXT',
    sasl_mechanism='SCRAM-SHA-512',
    sasl_plain_username='admin',      # your privileged user
    sasl_plain_password='admin12345'  # password
)

delete_acls = admin.delete_acls(
    [
        ACLFilter(principal='User:user1',
                  host='*',
                  operation=ACLOperation.ANY,
                  permission_type=ACLPermissionType.ANY,
                  resource_pattern=ResourcePattern(ResourceType.TOPIC, 'topic2')),
        ACLFilter(principal='User:user1',
                  host='*',
                  operation=ACLOperation.ANY,
                  permission_type=ACLPermissionType.ANY,
                  resource_pattern=ResourcePattern(ResourceType.GROUP, 'group2'))
    ]

)

print(delete_acls)
```

The array submitted by `admin.delete_acls`, you can write multiple ACLFilters to find the acls to delete.

###### describe acls

```py
acl_filter = ACLFilter(
    principal=None,
    host='*',
    operation=ACLOperation.ANY,
    permission_type=ACLPermissionType.ANY,
    resource_pattern=ResourcePattern(ResourceType.TOPIC,'topic2')
)

result = admin.describe_acls(acl_filter)
print(result)
```